# PayPal upgrade from Sandbox to Production, not found error

Tags: php, paypal

My application was working fine with paypal sanbox account but when I put my production API credentials and make application to accept real payments it is giving me:

`"This webpage is not available"` error on this url:

> "https://www.live.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-95X1447957597540A".

I am making express checkout and credit card payments using paypal.
And I have my personal paypal account and developer account. And I am currently testing with my personal account API credentials for production purpose.

*Does it require to create a new Classic App to go live?*

*And if yes than can I and my client both create same app?*

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use live.paypal.com.  The live server is just www.paypal.com.

Comment: I just again checked my code and I realised that when I tries to use it for production my code was creating live.paypal.com url. Thanks for your help. :)